# Compile error for namespaces?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reference

I had weird compile errors. When I opened a project of mine today, suddenly I received over 100 errors. It gives even error for try catch, foreach and all those functions under system and Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace. I have also class libraries and although references are looking added, main project doesnt recognize references as well. I tried clean solution, rebuilt solution, cleared my aspnet tmp folder, re-added references but no help. what could be the problem? anyone experienced such problem. 
PS, my VS2010 isnt spoiled because any other project works fine,even with same class libraries.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try checking that the Target Framework in "Compile | Advanced Compile Options" hasn't been changed to an older version, and that the Target CPU is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You probably somehow changed to targeting the COMPACT framework, instead of the normal .net 3.5 or 4.0 framework.